# Punctuation and capitalization

Tags: punctuation

Put correct puntuations and capital words:

> bangladesh is a small country with a population of over sixteen crores she can hardly make headway so we should work hard to keep pace with the rest of the world

I have thought about 2 answers:

> (1) Bangladesh is a small country with a population of over sixteen crores. 
>   She can hardly make headway. So, we should work hard to keep pace with the rest of the world.
>
> (2) Bangladesh is a small country. With a population of over sixteen crores, she can hardly make headway. So we should work hard to keep pace with the rest of the world.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are possible. Capitalization and punctuation look correct in both.

The difference is in meaning. Answer 2 implies that the reason Bangladesh can hardly make headway is because of the huge population (by the way, what is a "crore"? Is it a million?)

Answer 1 makes no such implication. The sentence about "headway" seems to be lacking some explanation. But even in number 2, we don't know what is meant by "headway" (towards what end?) it's hard to say whether one answer is better than the other.

Anyway, a third possibility would be like #2, but with comma instead of period after "headway".

(By the way, in America we would not usually refer to any country as "she". )

Comment: 1 crore is 10 million
....overpopulation is truly a big problem for our country,Bangladesh